# Shopify click counter

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify, click-counting

I'm trying to make a simple click counter on my shopify page for all the clients/customers to be able to see.

```
  var a = []; // array of indexes
  var num_clicks = []; // stored number of clicks for each collection

  // Get titles of each collection to use as index
  a[0] = {{linklists[page.handle].links[0].title| json}};
  a[1] = {{linklists[page.handle].links[1].title| json}};
  a[2] = {{linklists[page.handle].links[2].title| json}};
  a[3] = {{linklists[page.handle].links[3].title| json}};
  a[4] = {{linklists[page.handle].links[4].title| json}};
  a[5] = {{linklists[page.handle].links[5].title| json}};
  a[6] = {{linklists[page.handle].links[6].title| json}};
  a[7] = {{linklists[page.handle].links[7].title| json}};
  a[8] = {{linklists[page.handle].links[8].title| json}};

  // Set all number of clicks to 0
  for(var i=0;i<9;i++){
    num_clicks[a[i]] = 0;
  }

  // counter
  function fn(clicked){
    var target; // some target number 
    var x; // div id where I'm putting the counter
    if(num_clicks[clicked] < min_click-1){
      num_clicks[clicked] += 1;
      document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = num_clicks[clicked]+" / " + target;
    } else{
      num_clicks[clicked] += 1;
      document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = num_clicks[clicked] +" / " + target;
      document.getElementById(clicked).href = "SOME LINK";
      return true;
    }
  }
```

This code works fine and all on one computer but I need it to show the same number "globally" and heard it has to written in server-side. but I can't figure out how to send the counter to the server and retrieve it. if you could help me out with this, it'd be very appreciated.

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Well, that's a pretty broad request. What are you writing your server-side in? PHP, Javascript w/ Node.js, Ruby, etc. Are you familiar with AJAX? More so, are you familiar with WebSockets? Because you need to send the value up to the server and have it save it somewhere then either your clients need to be long polling with AJAX or allow the server to push the data out to them via WebSockets.

Comment: I'm going to be writing the server-side with Python and save the data into mySQL.

Comment: That's still a lot to start from. Get a basic Python server running, figure out how to handle AJAX requests, then come back for more information as needed.